# Is data freed when all instances of std::shared_ptr pointing to it are destroyed?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I want to know if it is necessary to call reset() for every instance of std::shared_ptr in program for memory to get released or not? i.e is memory freed when there is no instance of std::shared_ptr pointing to it although some of them have not called reset() before getting destroyed?

For instance if we have a function like:

```
void func() 
{

   std::shared_ptr<int> p1(new int(5));
   std::shared_ptr<int> p2 = p1; //Both now own the memory.

   p1.reset(); //Memory still exists, due to p2.

}
```

When the function finishes and p1 and p2 are destroyed, is the memory freed despite not calling reset() of p2?

Comment: When a shared_ptr goes out of scope, the memory will be freed, so yes. You don't even need to be calling `reset()` on `p1`

Comment: What would be the point of shared pointers if it wasn't? You'd be back to manual memory management, and the shared pointer would just be pointless overhead.

Comment: @Mat at least it counts the references to memory and deletes it when the last one calls reset().

Comment: Sure, so it's a bit better than a plain pointer, but still pointlessly error-prone. BTW, your question's answered by just looking at the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can easily verify the answer using the following simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
   ~A() { std::cout << "Came to A::~A()\n";}
};

int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<A> p1(new A);
   std::shared_ptr<A> p2 = p1;
   std::shared_ptr<A> p3 = p2;

   return 0;
}
```

This is what I get when I run the program.

```
Came to A::~A()
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary to call `reset()`. After all instances of a shared pointer go out of scope, the memory pointed to internally will be freed. The reset function only resets the instance that it is called on. Read about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/